# How to create controllers and views to display a User's profile with Devise gem as authentication mechanism?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, devise, user-registration

I'm using Devise as the authentication mechanism for my app.
I want to add additional information to my user model, like User statistics, profile pic , and other relevant information about the user.How to achieve this?.
 Even after creating "rails g devise : views" it creates only the views which I can customize it doesn't give me of its controllers to edit.

Else can I edit the devise gem itself to fit my requirements ?
 I have never tried to customize a GEM. Any links to start with customizing a existing gem?

Answer (score 4):

Devise itself is a Rails engine and you can override any of its functionality by creating a copy of the file you wish to change in your local directory.  When Rails begins to look for an appropriate controller for a request, it will first check the local application, then vendor/gems, and then the loaded gems themselves.

In the case of Devise, they mention that modifying controllers should be done in this way:

> **Configuring controllers**
>
> If the customization at the views level is not enough, you can customize each controller by following these steps:
>
> 1) Create your custom controller, for
>   example a Admins::SessionsController:
>
> ```
> class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
> end
> ```
>
> 2) Tell the router to use this controller:
>
> ```
> devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => "admins/sessions" }
> ```
>
> 3) And since we changed the controller, it won’t use the "devise/sessions" views, so remember to copy "devise/sessions" to "admin/sessions".
>
> Remember that Devise uses flash messages to let users know if sign in was successful or failed. Devise expects your application to call "flash[:notice]" and "flash[:alert]" as appropriate.

Here is the source of the quote: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise